# Could Pressure Alone at room temperature be used to confine a Plasma and sustain hydrogen fusion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fusion

I'd like someone more knowledgeable of physics pressure and fusion, to weigh in on my idea for sustaining a plasma using off-the-shelf parts.

The pressure at the core of the sun is 1 trillion Earth atmospheres which sustains proton-chain hydrogen fusion into helium.   Why not build the apparatus at the lowest point in the ocean which immediately gets you to 1000 atmospheres.  Use a large off the shelf pressure-chamber vessel capable of 1000 atmospheres which increases the inside pressure to 1 million Earth atmospheres.  Finally, buy another smaller pressure chamber, to be put inside the 1 million atmosphere chamber, and increase that to 1000 atmospheres.  In the core you have 1 trillion atmospheres of pressure, there you can use your high energy laser emitter and heat your pellet of solid hydrogen to 100 million degrees.  The fusion occurs and heats the surrounding liquid metal, then it's all engineering detail to heat to activation, pump in the fuel pellets, charge and strobe the laser, then pump out the heat from the metal after fusion, to run a turbine.

I get the feeling I'm not the first person to think of this.  Is there something I'm missing, such as pressure and heat alone isn't enough to confine the plasma needed for fusion?

Comment: Pressures do not multiply.  With an outside pressure of 1000 atm, the maximum pressure inside a 1000 atm pressure vessel is 2000 atm, not 1 million atm.

Comment: Ah, pressure is additive, not multiplicative. I suppose it would be out of the question to Russian-Doll onion layer enough of these to create the pressure required.

Comment: Right, a Russian-Doll setup won't help much. The inner layers are going to get crushed long before you reach even deuterium fusion pressure. And even if you somehow solved that problem, I suspect that your reactor would still need to be fairly large, requiring vast amounts of heavy elements (i.e., heavier than hydrogen) to construct it.